# I have this below query working fine but not grouping quarterly, I want both row in single with quarter data

Tags: php, sql

this is my query

```
select
    a.TrustMemName,
    a.DonorFirstName,
    CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between '2017-01-01' and '2017-03-31' THEN sum(a.AmountFulfilled) 
      ELSE null
   END as qurter1,
   CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between '2017-04-01' and '2017-06-30' THEN sum(a.AmountFulfilled) 
                ELSE null
          END as qurter2,
   CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between '2017-07-01' and '2017-09-30' THEN sum(a.AmountFulfilled) 
                ELSE null
            END as quarter3,
   CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between '2017-10-01' and '2017-12-31' THEN sum(a.AmountFulfilled) 
                ELSE null
            END as quarter4

from
   commitmentcomplete as a
where a.YourCommitmentId=171
group by a.YourCommitmentId,QUARTER(a.DateFulfilled1)
```

--------------------output-------------------------

```
TrustMemName | DonorFirstName | qurter1 | qurter2 | quarter3 | quarter4    
nithin       |   xdfcdg       |   3000  |  null   |   null   |  null    
nithin       |   xdfcdg       |   null  |  1500   |   null   |  null
```

---

Here i need 1500 in the first row in quarter2 column, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put  the `CASE` inside the `SUM`

```
SUM( CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between '2017-01-01' and '2017-03-31' 
          THEN a.AmountFulfilled          
     END) as qurter1,
SUM( CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between '2017-04-01' and '2017-06-30' 
          THEN a.AmountFulfilled          
     END) as qurter2,
SUM( CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between '2017-07-01' and '2017-09-30' 
          THEN a.AmountFulfilled          
     END) as qurter3,
SUM( CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between '2017-10-01' and '2017-12-31' 
          THEN a.AmountFulfilled          
     END) as qurter4
```

I remove the `ELSE NULL` because  that is the default option.

And you only need `GROUP BY a.YourCommitmentId` no need to include `QUARTER()`

Comment: do you mean a different from mine? If my answer solve your problem remember mark it as accept (green tick)

Answer (score 0):

Do the changes as suggested by Juan and also, please remove QUARTER(a.DateFulfilled1) from the group by clause.